# How can I include a code from another file commands

Tags: node.js

I am using this code, and what I want is for the commands to come from another file to make the index.js cleaner

```
const tmi = require('tmi.js');

const client = new tmi.Client({
    options: { debug: true },
    channels: [ 'my_name' ]
});

client.connect();

client.on('message', (channel, tags, message, self) => {
    // Ignore echoed messages.
    if(self) return;

    if(message.toLowerCase() === '!hello') {
        // "@alca, heya!"
        client.say(channel, `@${tags.username}, heya!`);
    }
});
```

In the index include the code

```
// index.js
// ======
var commands = require('./commands');

    const tmi = require('tmi.js');
var commands = require('./commands');
const client = new tmi.Client({
    options: { debug: true },
    channels: [ 'my_name' ]
});

client.connect();

client.on('message', (channel, tags, message, self) => {
    // Ignore echoed messages.
    if(self) return;
// I replace the command with the file
  commands();
});
```

I have the commands file structured in this way.

```
// commands.js
// ========
module.exports = function (channel, tags, message, self) {
    if(message.toLowerCase() === '!hello') {
        // "@alca, heya!"
        client.say(channel, `@${tags.username}, heya!`);
    }
  }
```

But it doesn't work for me, I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

---

I have republished it from a new account, it has not allowed me to access the one with which I made the query. And it does not allow me to vouch for the lack of reputation. [How can I include a code from another file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73126904/how-can-i-include-a-code-from-another-file)

---

Responding to @jabaa's answer.

- The problem you have when typing !hello should give the answer Heya! which would be client.say(channel, `@${tags.username}, heya!`);

@Dave Newton the intention is only to load the information from commands.js so that the index is cleaner if I use the direct code it works but when I use Commands(); It doesn't make any response.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 2 files in the same directory

- `/foo/bar/commands.js`
- `/foo/bar/main.js`

You can define `commands.js` like this:

```js
exports = module.exports = {
  someFunction,
  anotherFunction,
}

function someFunction(text) {
  console.log(`in someFunction: ${text}`);
}

function anotherFunction(text) {
  console.log(`in anotherFunction(): ${text}`);
}
```

And then you can pull that into `main.js` like so:

```js
const cmds = require('./commands');

cmds.someFunction('hello, there!');
cmds.anotherFunctio('and again!');
```

and get the following written to the console:

```
in someFunction(): hello, there!
in anotherFunction(): and again!
```

If you set the default export as the function itself,

```
exports = modules.exports = someFunction(text) {
  console.log(`in someFunction(): ${text}`);
}
```

Then what's returned from the `require()` is that function:

```
const foo = require('./commands.js');

foo('hello, there!'):
```

and running that you get:

```
in someFunction(): hello, there!
```

Comment: I've tried the code you provided and it works the same as the one I made but it's not what I'm looking for. The intention is that it works as if it were only index.js and the content of commands.js works as an include that incorporates the code and is interpreted as one so that it can work. I don't know if I should use fs.read